# Beginning a formal essay with a spoiler alert?

Tags: internet, mla, convention

I'm writing a literary analysis piece on Shirley Jackson's *The Haunting of Hill House*. Online, such analyses are often preceded by a warning that the contents of the page contains detailed information about the plot so that someone who hasn't read the book yet would know not to read it if they don't want the plot spoiled. Does such a "spoiler warning" have a place in a formal essay? The format of the essay is MLA.

Comment: Formal essays typically have enough in their titles and format to not require spoiler alerts. Hypothetical example: "Analysis of the ending of Some Soap Opera, Episode 1." People who are part of the intended audience of formal essays probably don't care about spoiler alerts - if they are reading the essay, they have probably searched for it intentionally.

Comment: Absolutely not.  Anyone reading a literary analysis certainly expects that the piece will discuss key aspects of the work, including major plot points.  That applies even when the analysis is presented on the web, supposing it is labeled as what it is.  A spoiler warning would be out of place inside the piece itself.

Comment: What does "MLA" mean?

Comment: @TrevorD 'MLA' means 'Modern Language Association'. OP is referring to its established style (http://www.mla.org/MLA-Style) for presentation and referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'formal' you mean that your essay will be academically assessed or published, then it would be *inappropriate* to include a spoiler warning.  That would literally make your piece look amateurish.

Spoiler warnings are suitably considerate in the perfectly legitimate realm where enthusiasts discuss a text and people primarily hope to enjoy the plot.  When I am chatting about a text in the pub, I am speaking in this way as an amateur or enthusiast, and I strive not to reveal plot points.

When writing academically-orientated material, however, that would not be an appropriate consideration.  I would look amateurishly clumsy if I were to write about *Hamlet* while coyly skirting the fact that (almost) everyone dies by the end.  I *expect* readers to be familiar with the text we are discussing.  If their primary concern is enjoying the plot, then *they* have simply selected an inappropriate piece to read.

We can all write as both enthusiasts/fans and academics, depending on circumstances.  The two types of material work differently.

Answer (score 1):

> "Does such a "spoiler warning" have a place in a formal essay?"

It is courteous and considerate of you to ask this question, but unless you plan to informally publish your essay (online, for instance), you may assume that your reader has already read the book and that no "spoiler alert" is required. In short, such an alert would be inappropriate in a formal essay.